# add class to div if id is equal to value from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i need to add a class to a div if its id is equal to a value from list:

```
list = ["a1", "a2", "a3"]

<div id="a1"></div>
<div id="b1"></div>
<div id="c1"></div>
<div id="a3"></div>
```

any help is appreciated

thanks
J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = ["a1", "a2", "a3"];

$(list).each(function(){
    $('#'+this).addClass('added');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qgeVH/2/

**EDIT**

BoltClock's suggestion:

```
$.each(list, function(){
    $('#'+this).addClass('added');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qgeVH/4/

Comment: I think it should be `$.each(list, function() {` instead of `$(list).each(function() {`. Or does jQuery support wrapping arrays too? If so, that's cool.

Comment: @user664546 - No problem. @BoltClock - What would be the difference? Is it performance?

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Not performance - I always thought you'd use `$.each` when looping through a plain array while you use `$().each` to loop through a jQuery set.

Comment: @BoltClock - Yeah, I saw someone else do that before, in `$(array)`. I guess they're probably synonymous.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) and [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray):

```
var list = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'];

$('div').each(function() {
    if ($.inArray(this.id, list)) {
        $(this).addClass('class');
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any appreciable different between your method and mine?

Comment: @Jared Farrish: They achieve the same goal in different ways. I loop through the divs, you loop through the array. I guess.

Comment: I was just wondering if one was more preferable than the other, for some reason.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Looks like OP picked yours :)

Comment: I see that; I imagine mine was easier to visually understand, maybe. As to using `$.each` instead, is there a performance improvement?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing came to my mind is that you can create a for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
     if(document.getElementById(list[i])) {
       document.getElementById(list[i]).className = 'added2';
     }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qgeVH/3/

Comment: Also, I don't know why the `break` is in there, since that will short circuit before it finds all. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qgeVH/1/

Comment: Since the question says "need to add a class to a div" I thought he was asking for a div only. If there is more than one then obviously removing the break is crucial.

Comment: Well, his example shows four DIVs and three array pieces. I edited to remove the break.

Answer (score 1):

here is an alternative [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/LRWQ6/) you can turn the list into a string delimited by ",#" to create a selector

```
var list = ["a1", "a2", "a3"];

var joined_list = list.join(',#'); //turn into string
// you need to add a "#" to the beginning of the string to make a proper selector
$('#'+joined_list).addClass('foo');
```

as commented this could be shortend

```
 var list = ["a1", "a2", "a3"];
 $('#'+list.join(',#')).addClass('foo');
```

Comment: @Jared Farrish I just wanted to take it stup by step but yes you can easily put the list join in the selector

Comment: The only thing I don't like about your example is it obliterates the original list variable. You might also add a textual note that describes why it works (as in the joined list in plaintext).